# Image not found in asset catalog for Swift Package Bundle

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

My app is made of many modules, each of which is a Swift Package. I have a case where I want to show an image that is provided by another module. This means PackageA is some sort of UI library; it gets some of its assets from another module, PackageB, which has a `Assets.xcassets` catalog. The PackageB offers APIs for those assets, like for the `name: String` and the `bundle: Bundle` (which is `Bundle.module`).

I use the asset like this: `Image(iconData.asset.imageName, bundle: iconData.asset.bundle)`

When I build and try to access the resources, I get the error: `No image named 'myImage.png' found in asset catalog for <Bundle url>`. The bundle URL is valid.

The module that offers the assets has this declaration in its `Package` file:

```
.target(
    name: "PackageName",
    dependencies: [],
    resources: [
        .process("Resources")
    ]),
```

[image]

Side note: the json files shown in the capture screen are correctly loaded.

What am I missing? Are there restrictions for such use?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was to reference the image by its `filename+extension` pattern, instead of just its asset label.

So when I was creating my SwiftUI.Image, like I mention in my question, I used this: `Image(iconData.asset.imageName, bundle: iconData.asset.bundle)`. The `iconData.asset.imageName` was built with `"\(fileName).\(fileExtension)"`. Removing the extension and only using `fileName` fixed my issue.

Maybe this can help someone!